# MySQL Pattern matching to find specific text

Tags: mysql, regex

My working database is from a webforum. In it, there's a table containing all the data of posts (I.e. the text a user submitted within a thread). These posts contain a column called `message` which is the actual content of the post. A post can contain any character, as well as smilies. Smilies are indicated by a colon, immediately followed by a short description of variable length and again a colon. I.e. `:clap:`. A single post can contain multiple smilies.

I am trying to come up with a way to pull out a list of all smilies within the posts table.

What I have working so far is a query that pulls a list of posts containing at least two colons:

```
SELECT 
    thread_id
    , post_id
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(message, ':', 2), ':', -1) 
FROM 
    xf_post
WHERE 
    ROUND((CHAR_LENGTH(message) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(message, ':', ""))) / CHAR_LENGTH(':')) > 1
LIMIT 50
```

This works, but will also return messages where a user for whatever reason included multiple colons, like for instance `random : text followed : by more text`, or a timestamp: `00:00:12345`.

What I'm hoping to achieve is to return all occurrences of alphanumeric characters enclosed between colons, without any spaces. (Yes, this will remove all smilies that are purely numeric, but `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`).

I fiddled with `REGEXP`, and came up with the following: `[:][a-zA-Z]+(?=:)[:]` which according to [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bX8gEP/1) yields exactly what I want.

How can I use this to capture the output, and only see the values between the semi-colons, and preferably in such a way it would show all occurrences of a smilie within a single post?

Thank you.

Comment: maybe you can take a look to REGEXP_SUBSTR() https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr

Comment: @SimonlucaLandi - Thanks. That solvs part of my issue. I can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR(message, '[:][a-zA-Z]+(?=:)[:]')` to show the smiliecode.

Comment: Is "a short description" limited to text with no spaces?

Comment: @RickJames Yes, it is. I.e. `:clap:`, `:cry:`, `:love:`, etc. Most forums come with a limited amount of pre-defined smilies, but admins can add as many as they like, using whatever descriptive term they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SimonlucaLandi helped me at least figure out the way to display the results. My final query:

```
SELECT 
    thread_id
    , post_id
    , REGEXP_SUBSTR(message, '':[a-zA-Z]+:'')
FROM 
    xf_post
WHERE 
    message REGEXP '':[a-zA-Z]+:''
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Why not use a simple `':[a-zA-Z]+:'`?

Comment: Note:  This requires MariaDB 10.0 or MySQL 8.0.

Comment: Another issue:  What if the messages contains two colons (:), just as this Comment does.  You might want to avoid any result that contains a space.  This might be done with a `HAVING  .. NOT LIKE '% %'`

Comment: @RickJames Good, what I am driving at is `[a]` = `a` and `(?=abcdefghijklmnop)abcdefghijklmnop` = `abcdefghijklmnop`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - You are right.  I was dramatically misreading `(?=:)` as `[^:]*`.  (Deleting my comments.)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Interesting. I tried using a colon within the regex before, but that at the time didn't work. Might have been me messing up the syntax in another spot, though. I figured that seeing it was some "special" character, perhaps it needed to be put within the brackets. (As you can tell, reg ex is not something I'm overly familiar with). I'll update the answer to reflect your comment.